Outputting to curses' window from another function
Let's say I have set up two files.
One is main.py:
from .terminal import current_instance

current_instance.addstr("Hello world!")
current_instance.refresh()

Other is terminal.py:
import curses

current_instance = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()


When I run main.py, the window is initiated, text printed, but after that the window closes and quits the program. If I try to put a loop in terminal.py, it'll just block the program, and putting a loop in main.py would be inconvenient as I have other files that should also output text to the terminal window.
So is it possible to make the window "persistent", while being non-blocking?
I tried calling nodelay() and making an asynchronous function that calls getch() infinitely, and while the window is persistent, the function is still blocking.

why do you close window? terminal can't exists without window. Better show minimal working code which you use to run other code, close window, etc.

I do not close window. I initiate the window and don't do anything that can even remotely be related to closing it. It closes by itself.

I don't know curses but usually GUI frameworks needs to run special function which runs endless loops which gets events (mouse, keyboard, etc) from system and use it to update widgets in window. If GUI doesn't run this loop then it ends work and it close window (or usually it doesn't even open window). Your code may also need to run some loop to keep running terminal - but it may need to run it in separated thread if you want to run other code at the same time.

I think curse works in linear way and could run loop in terminal.py but it would need to run code in separate thread. But usually GUIs don't like to run in separated threads and it needs to use queue to send data to thread which runs GUI, and this thread has to update GUI. I think you have to redesign all logic in your code. main.py should create terminal, and import all other code, run this code, and finally use loop to keep it running.

BTW: if other files that should also output text to the terminal means you run other code in main.py then last code should run loop to keep running all code. But if you means you wnat run other scripts as separated programs then it is useless because they will create own terminal - not uses existing terminal - and it would start terminal as separate program which use queue, sockets or web server to get data from other programs.
